Как "разкирпичить" Mijia Robot Vacuum-Mop 3C?
пожалуйста помогите. Прошил Mijia Robot Vacuum-Mop 3C через сайт mindsolo
Была версия 4.3.3_0025
Обновлялся на 4.1.8_0002 (тестируется)
После 20 минут закрыл на телефоне mihome и тепер пылесос ни включается ни выключается, пробовал одновременно зажать home start не реагирует.На задней стороне под крышкой около батареи есть микро разъем, подключив его к компьютеру с помощью fastboot я получил следующую инфу:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\platform-tools>fastboot devices  
396932SD2303C01531       fastboot 

AND

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\platform-tools>fastboot getvar all
(bootloader) version:0.4
(bootloader) version-bootloader:U-Boot 2017.09-g8886bdd-dirty
(bootloader) version-baseband:N/A
(bootloader) product:evb_rk3308
(bootloader) serialno:396932SD2303C01531
(bootloader) secure:yes
(bootloader) max-download-size:0x04000000
(bootloader) logical-block-size:0x200
(bootloader) erase-block-size:0xffffffff
(bootloader) partition-type:uboot:U-Boot
(bootloader) partition-type:trust:U-Boot
(bootloader) partition-type:security:U-Boot
(bootloader) partition-type:misc:U-Boot
(bootloader) partition-type:boot_a:U-Boot
(bootloader) partition-type:boot_b:U-Boot
(bootloader) partition-type:system_a:U-Boot
(bootloader) partition-type:system_b:U-Boot
(bootloader) partition-type:vbmeta_a:U-Boot
(bootloader) partition-type:vbmeta_b:U-Boot
(bootloader) partition-type:userdata:U-Boot
(bootloader) partition-size:uboot:0x200000
(bootloader) partition-size:trust:0x200000
(bootloader) partition-size:security:0x200000
(bootloader) partition-size:misc:0x100000
(bootloader) partition-size:boot_a:0xa00000
(bootloader) partition-size:boot_b:0xa00000
(bootloader) partition-size:system_a:0x2600000
(bootloader) partition-size:system_b:0x2600000
(bootloader) partition-size:vbmeta_a:0x100000
(bootloader) partition-size:vbmeta_b:0x100000
(bootloader) partition-size:userdata:0x617be00
(bootloader) unlocked:no
(bootloader) off-mode-charge:not implemented
(bootloader) battery-voltage:not implemented
(bootloader) variant:userdebug
(bootloader) battery-soc-ok:no
(bootloader) is-userspace:no
(bootloader) slot-count:2
(bootloader) has-slot:uboot:no
(bootloader) has-slot:trust:no
(bootloader) has-slot:security:no
(bootloader) has-slot:misc:no
(bootloader) has-slot:boot:yes
(bootloader) has-slot:system:yes
(bootloader) has-slot:vbmeta:yes
(bootloader) has-slot:userdata:no
(bootloader) current-slot:a
(bootloader) slot-suffixes:a,b
(bootloader) slot-successful:a:no
(bootloader) slot-successful:b:no
(bootloader) slot-unbootable:a:yes
(bootloader) slot-unbootable:b:yes
(bootloader) slot-retry-count:a:0
(bootloader) slot-retry-count:b:0

Есть рабочий пылесос этой же модели, но если его так же подключить,то компьютер его не видит и команды fastboot не работают. В общем если у вас есть идеи, прошу помогите.
